# C# how to store parsed data inside application?

Tags: c#, database

This is rather general question, but it relates to overall application design. I'm trying to create application that follows class design standards and I'm struggling with one aspect that is how to store information internally.

For example I can create a class for a Movie with couple fields:

- title
- year
- director

So when I parse xml files that holds this metadata I would load them into a public List. I'm not sure if this is a right approach? Since List is an instance of an object, maybe it does not belong in a class that defines Movie?

It is public list it would be available in other parts of application.

I do not see any point of parsing xml files multiple times during application activity. The same goes for accessing database like SQLite.

I looked at Singleton design and I'm not sure if that is a right approach? Plus based on Singleton samples I viewed, I do not know if I can define fields that I mentioned before.

So, my question is. How do you deal with metadata or file paths from scanned folder? Where do you keep this information inside your application?

Thank you

Comment: Where it's appropriate.  It's unclear what your problem is, other than you're thinking about it too hard.  Prototype it.

Comment: Dependency injection, but don't view OOD as the only path or any programming paradigm in that matter. "In the beginner's mind there are many possibilities, in the expert's there are few." always be the beginner when it comes to art including but not limited application design.

Comment: I'd also like to expand on the singleton patter in a few words, it works and is valid for OOD as in the real world we have to go to something to get information (HR for example to get information on our insurance) but it has been abused like the `goto` you'll never hear about. I'd check out the MV* patterns like MVVM or MVC.

Comment: @Will Maybe I'm thinking about this too hard. But I would like to know what other people do with this common situation.

Comment: @Philip Rollins I did not think about MVVM and MVC. I will take a look at them. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The class which parses the XML file *shouldn't* store the result. If that class parses a list of movies, it should just return an `IEnumerable<Movie>`, and then the caller of that class can store the result wherever it wants to.

Comment: I thought so. Class it's just a blueprint for an object. So basically List<of T> will be available to other methods during execution of public static void Main()

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty general question and there are a number of ways to do it depending on your [NFRs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement).  The following is a pretty basic way that should be forward compatible with a number of approaches.

1. Declare the list within main program scope as an `IList<Movie>`.
2. Write a class that implements IList (e.g. `class MovieList:IList<Movie>`) that exposes the data you need.  It can cache it if you want.  It doesn't have to.  For now, write the [simplest code that could work](http://www.agilenutshell.com/simplest_thing).
3. Later, in the main program, you can change the declaration of your IList to use an IoC container to instantiate the IList (e.g. `_myList = Container.Resolve<IList<Movie>>`.  That way you can substitute different data providers, or substitute a mock provider for unit testing.
4. Later, you can change the implementation of `MovieList` to include caching, or store the data in a DB, or whatever you want.  Or you can totally rewrite it in a new class and change the configuration of your IoC container to point at the new class.  You will have all sorts of options.  (The decision to cache or not to cache will ultimately depend on NFRs such as storage capacity, performance, and concurrency/[ACID](http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/definition/ACID))

The point is to write down the bones of what your program truly needs, and worry about the details of where and when to store stuff later.

I don't think it is a good idea to simply store the whole list in a global variable without some kind of abstractification.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you. I have most of the pieces of my app done, but this is my first attempt to do it using classes. I used global variable for that purpose before. Unfortunately some things are not so clear when you are starting with OOP. Once again thank you!